# In the first cond statement I'm trying to see whey this won't work. Or How can I get it to work?

Tags: scheme, racket

In this first conditional statement

```
( (and (null? list) (and (= s1 s2) (= s1_length s2_length))) s1_length 0)
```

I've also tried this, where I get a return but it's always 0.

```
 ((null? list) (and (= s1 s2) (= s1_length s2_length))  s1_length 0)
```

I need all those to return true before it will return s1_length, but is an error.

> *** ERROR: pair required, but got ()

Here is the the full script:

```
(define mes
 
  (lambda (list s1 s2 s1_length s2_length count)
   
    (newline)
    (display list)
    (newline)
    (display s1)
    (display s2)
    (display s1_length)
    (display s2_length)
    (newline)
   
   
    (cond
      ( (and (null? list) (and (= s1 s2) (= s1_length s2_length))) s1_length 0)
      ( > (mes (cdr list) (+ s1 (car list)) s2 (+ 1 s1_length) s2_length count) (mes (cdr list) s1 (+ s2 (car list)) s1_length (+ 1 s2_length) count)
                      (mes (cdr list) (+ s1 (car list)) s2 (+ 1 s1_length) s2_length count) )
      ( > (mes (cdr list) s1 s2 s1_length s2_length count) (mes (cdr list) s1 (+ s2 (car list)) s1_length (+ 1 s2_length) count)
                        (mes (cdr list) s1 s2 (len '(s1)) (len '(s2)) count) )
      ( (mes (cdr list) s1 (+ s2 (car list)) s1_length (+ 1 s2_length) count) ))
     
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are not conditional statements, they are conditional clauses in a `cond` expression.

Each clause has the form `(condition expression)` and its value is `expression`.
The full form is

```
(cond ((condition1 expression1)
       (condition2 expression2)
       ...
       (conditionN expressionN)))
```

If `expressionX` is in turn a sequence of expressions, its value is the value of the last sub-expression, which is 0 in your first attempt.
It is equivalent to

```
((and (null? list) (= s1 s2) (= s1_length s2_length)) 
        (begin 
             s1_length 
             0))
```

In your second attempt, the condition is `(null? list)` and the value expression is

```
(begin
    (and (= s1 s2) (= s1_length s2_length))  
     s1_length 
     0)
```

which is also 0.

In your next two clauses, the condition is `<`, which is truth-y since it isn't `#f`.
Since your first clause only handles the empty list if the other two conditions are also true, you're passing an empty list to `car` or `cdr` in the second clause, and this is the immediate reason for your error message.

In the final clause, the condition is `(mes (cdr list) s1 (+ s2 (car list)) s1_length (+ 1 s2_length) count)`, without a value expression.

There is also the mystery of the `count` parameter, which appears to serve no purpose; it's just passed through all recursions and then ignored.

It is difficult to say how to fix your function, as it's not clear at all what it is supposed to do.

Comment: It's taking a list of number then finding if there are equal sets.  (1 2 3 4) would be true because (1 4) == (2 3) due to each adding up to 5.  Not overly hard I'm just new to Scheme.

Comment: Your second and third conditions imply that the result should be a number, not a boolean.  (Also, open your REPL and check the values of `(len '(s1))` and `'(s1)`.)